# JPA @OneToOne Mapping a relationship with ReadOnly Oracle data without primary key

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, primary-key

**Preamble** 
 An Oracle DB read-only(I don't have access) has the following two tables: 
**person**

```
person table

| id   | name   | gender |
| --   | ------ | ------ |
| 2001 | Moses  | M      |
| 2002 | Luke   | M      |
| 2003 | Maryam | F      |

PK(id)
```

**reference**

```
reference table

| sep   | guid     | table_name |
| ---   | -------- | ---------- |
| 2001  | EA48-... | person     |
| 2002  | 047F-... | person     |
| 2003  | B23F-... | person     |
| 2003  | 3E3H-... | address    |
| 2001  | H2E0-... | address    |
| 2001  | 92E4-... | report     |

No PK, it is generated by some triggers
```

The person table is a straight forward table with a primary key. The reference table are generated via a trigger that stores the id(PK) in **sep** column of any table and the table name  that is store in **table_name** column (Note: Since no primary key, the reference table stores duplicate values in the **sep** column but distinct value into guid.)

**Requirement**
I need to use JPA to get the record from the reference table and map to the person record (person.**id** and other table.**id** are stored in reference.**sep** column) using Jackson as follows

```
{
 "id": 2001, 
 "name": "Moses", 
 "gender": "M", 
 "reference": {
   "sep": 2001, 
   "guid": "EA48-...",
   "tableName": "person"
 }
}
```

Entity (Person)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String gender;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "sep", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Reference reference;

 // Getters & Setters
}
```

Entity (Reference)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reference")
public class Reference implements Serializable {
  private Long sep;
  private String guid;
  private String tableName;

  //Getters & Setters
}
```

**Problem 1** 
JPA throws error of no **@Id** annotation on Reference table.

**Problem 2** 
If I add the **@Id** annotation on the sep field, JPA throws error of duplicate values for that column.

**Problem 3** 
If I add the **@Id** annotation on the guid field (it is unique field), JPA throws error of mapping a **Long** to a **String** field (*org.hibernate.TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class*)

**Question**
How can I structure the entities (**Person.java** and **Reference.java**) in order to come up with the output below:

```
{
 "id": 2001, 
 "name": "Moses", 
 "gender": "M", 
 "reference": {
   "sep": 2001, 
   "guid": "EA48-...",
   "tableName": "person"
 }
}
```

Comment: Put `@Id` on `sep` as well as `tableName` as those 2 columns create the unique identifier. As for the mapping you could attempt something with `@JoinColumns`, `@JoinColumn`, `@JoinColumnOrFormula`, `@JoinFormula`

Comment: Thanks @XtremeBaumer
I have tried that as well, but Hibernate errors "broken column mapping for: ..."

Comment: Gonna need the full error

Comment: - @XtremeBaumer 

.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: reference.id of: com.entity.sepdba.Person
 at

Comment: Put `@Id` on the 2 columns mentioned above and use `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "person", referencedColumnName = "tableName")), @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "sep")) })` for the `@OneToOne`

Comment: @XtremeBaumer - Great solution. It actually works. I just add '' (quotes) in the JoinFormula value ( = "'person'" tableName is VARCHAR) and it works. Thank you so much. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone looking to solve this kind of issue, I will be posting the solution that works for me following ***@XtremeBaumer*** suggestion in the comment.

Step 1: For the REFERENCE table, I made the JPA entity to have two ids (sep & table_name) by creating an extra composite Id class and using it in the Reference Entity.

```
public class RefId {
  private Long sep;
  private String tableName;
  
  //All args constructor
  //No args constructor
  //Setters & Getters
  //Override the equals() and hashCode() !very important
}
```

Step 2: Add the above class as a composite id to the Reference entity by using the @IdClass annotation. We must also declare and annotate the two fields with @Id in the Reference class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reference")
@IdClass(RefId.class) // Important if not using embeddable type
public class Reference implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long sep;
  private String guid;
  @Id
  private String tableName;

  //Getters & Setters
}
```

Step 3: In the Person entity, declare @OneToOne on the Reference entity and annotate it with @JoinColumnsOrFormulas as shown below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person")
public class Person implements Serializable {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String gender;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "sep", insertable = false, updatable = false)),
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "'person'", referencedColumnName = "tableName"))
  })
  private Reference reference;

 // Getters & Setters
}
```

This works fine in the scenario above. Note in the formula = @JoinFormula, it is like we are declaring the 'WHERE' clause i.e. WHERE table_name = 'person' (Don't miss the single quotes)

Lastly, by using the Jackson object mapper, I was able to get

```
{
 "id": 2001, 
 "name": "Moses", 
 "gender": "M", 
 "reference": {
   "sep": 2001, 
   "guid": "EA48-...",
   "tableName": "person"
 }
}
```

Thanks for your insight (@XtremeBaumer)

Answer (score 2):

Reference is the owner of the relationship and needs to be specified as such in either a unidirectional or bidirectional relationship

```
// Unidirection relationship
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    // Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
public class Reference implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String guid;
    private String tableName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sep", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Person person;
    //Getters & Setters
}

// Bidirection relationship
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
    private Reference reference;
    // Getters & Setters
}

@Entity
public class Reference implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String guid;
    private String tableName;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sep", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Person person;
    //Getters & Setters
}
```

Comment: Thanks @johnnyutts

Reference table stores information more than the person table. It has other entities' information as well. Mapping the owner Person in Reference will break other entities. I can't have Person in the Reference.

Comment: Also, the mapping happens on multiple columns, not just one, which is the real culprit here

Answer (score 1):

Same example for read any kind records from table reference:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reference")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "table_name")
public abstract class AbstractReferenceEntity {
    @Id
    private UUID guid;

    public UUID getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(UUID guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("person")
public class PersonReferenceEntity extends AbstractReferenceEntity {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "sep")
    private Person person;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public void setPerson(Person person) {
        this.person = person;
    }
}

// Read all types of records.
AbstractReferenceEntity e = this.em.find(AbstractReferenceEntity.class, sameUuid));

// Read only person type of records.
AbstractReferenceEntity e = this.em.find(PersonReferenceEntity, sameUuid);
```